# Ruby json gem is encoding html entities

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, html-entities

I make a hash called timeOffsets in my code

```
@timeOffsets = Hash.new
total=0
@sections.each do |i|
  @timeOffsets[i.shortcode] = total
  total+=i.length
end
```

And I render it in Javascript using to_json, :

```
timeOffsets=<%=@timeOffsets.to_json%>;
```

but I get it with the HTML entities encoded:

```
timeOffsets={&quot;Introduction_to_Lists&quot;:0,&quot;Removing_elements&quot;:693,&quot;Joining__join_&quot;:1490};
```

How do I stop it from encoding the HTML entities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
timeOffsets=<%=raw @timeOffsets.to_json%>
```

Use the raw view helper.